# Pointer dereference in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have not been able to understand how to dereference a pointer in VHDL.

What I have in mind is a C code like :

```
  int a;
  int* ptr_a;

  a = 42;
  ptr_a=&a;
  *ptr_a=451;// how can I do this ?
```

I tried to mimick this code in VHDL :

```
ptr_test : process
    type     ptr_integer is access integer;
    variable a     : integer;
    variable ptr_a : ptr_integer;
  begin
    a         := 42;
    ptr_a     := new integer'(a);
    report "ptr now points to a : ptr=" & str(ptr_a.all);
    ptr_a.all := 451;
    report "ptr modified        : ptr=" & str(ptr_a.all);
    report "a   is NOT modified : a  =" & str(a);
    wait;
  end process;
```

So how can I correctly modify a value through a pointer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't directly.  Access types are not "just like pointers" - they are to at least some extent distinct types of data storage.

This line does not create a pointer to `a`:

```
ptr_a     := new integer'(a);
```

It creates a data object with the same value as `a` and sets up `ptr_a` to reference it.

If you were to create another access type variable :

```
variable ptr_b : ptr_integer;
```

and set it to to point to `ptr_a`:

```
ptr_b := ptr_a;
```

then changes to `ptr_b.all` will reflect in `ptr_a.all`.

Comment: what does ptr_b.all signify here ?

Comment: `ptr_b.all` is how you get at the content of what the access type is referencing.

Answer (score 3):

"new" is the equivalent of the (C++ rather than C) "new" operation; invoking a constructor allocating an integer on the heap and initialising it to "a". (Naturally, you can "deallocate" it when done)

What you are looking for is `ptr_a := a'access;` which is the Ada way of accessing a global or local (stack) variable via a pointer : this is only legal if said variable has been declared "aliased" alerting the compiler to the fact there may be more than one view of it (and thus, preventing some nice optimisations). In C, everything is "aliased" whether you want it or not.

This is one of the aspects of Ada that didn't make it through the simplification process into VHDL : and it's difficult to see a good use for it. So there isn't an exact equivalent in VHDL.

Martin's answer just popped up : as he says, you CAN have 2 or more pointers to the same heap object.

Alternatively, explain what you are trying to achieve this way; there may be a VHDL alternative way of doing it.